# django-easyfilters template tag renders nothing

Tags: django

I have a django 1.7 and for clean experiment i tried to implement filters exactly as in documentation, but when open my page {{ booksfilter }} renders nothing. I tried anything, but nothing helps, these module worked on django 1.5, but now it is not working.
I already tried to to make code exactly as in documentation

Here is github issue
https://github.com/ionelmc/django-easyfilters/issues/10

Comment: Try using Django Debug Toolbar's template panel to see what's being passed for the booksfilter variable. http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.2/ It might be that django-tables2-simplefilter doesn't support 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!!!

When deleted all objects from my db - filter appears!
Then i tested and found something interesting:
I have a model ZayavkaDogovor, which has field
forma_oplati=models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=FORMA_OPLATI,verbose_name='Форма оплаты'), so choices for it is:
FORMA_OPLATI = (
('not_selected','Не выбрано'),
('beznal','Безналичный расчет'),
('nal','Наличный расчет'),
)
When there is russian symbols - it fails and not renders filters (just empty)
but when i changed it to (only english letters):
FORMA_OPLATI = (
('not_selected','amigrupp'),
('beznal','amigrupp'),
('nal','amigrupp'),
)
IT WORKED!
appending u' - WORKED to fix this!

## here how it works:

FORMA_OPLATI = (
('not_selected',u'Не выбрано'),
('beznal',u'Безналичный расчет'),
('nal',u'Наличный расчет'),
)
THANK YOU for this module!!!!!